# How to flank an enemy?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

How to get the status "flanked" on an enemy? I've tried attacking them from several different angles, with not reliable success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get two characters are more-or-less opposite sides of the enemy, right?  So you have to have at least 2 characters to flank, and they have to have an enemy roughly directly between your 2 characters.  Some terrible Preformatted examples:

```
YOU ENEMY YOU
```

Yay!  Flanking

```
YOU ENEMY
    YOU
```

Boo, no flanking

```
YOU ENEMY
        YOU
```

Sometimes flanking, but I can't seem to find a consensus.

Comment: Alternatively, there are status effects that cause enemies to be flanked.